# Agregar caracteres a un listado de IP

Tags: batch, ip

Tengo un listado de direcciones IP, el cual obtengo con otro batch que ya hice, pero me lo deja de la siguiente manera

1. 010093202001
2. 010093202002
3. 010093202003

lo que quisiera es poner un "." luego cada 3 números o sea que me quede así

1. 010.093.202.001
2. 010.093.202.002
3. 010.093.202.003

Intenté con esto

```
@echo off
set car1=.
set car2=
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (cajas.txt) do (echo %car1%%%i%car2%>>tmp.txt)
```

pero obviamente me pone los . delante porque no se me ocurre como usar el delims ya que no hay caracteres de delimitación.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy largo, cierto. Pero funciona :)

```
  @echo off
 set ip=010093202001
 set num1=%ip:~0,1%
 set num2=%ip:~1,1%
 set num3=%ip:~2,1%
 set num4=%ip:~3,1%
 set num5=%ip:~4,1%
 set num6=%ip:~5,1%
 set num7=%ip:~6,1%
 set num8=%ip:~7,1%
 set num9=%ip:~8,1%
 set num10=%ip:~9,1%
 set num11=%ip:~10,1%
 set num12=%ip:~11,1%

 set final=%num1%%num2%%num3%.%num4%%num5%%num6%.%num7%%num8%%num9%.%num10%%num11%%num12%

echo %final%
```

Este codigo lo puedes adaptar para que use la IP que recibas del otro archivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, al final tuve que modificar algunas cosas porque debía incluirlo en un for que leyera una lista. Pero sin la idea principal que me diste nunca hubiese llegado a esto

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, al final tuve que modificar algunas cosas porque debía incluirlo en un for que leyera una lista. Pero sin la idea principal que me diste nunca hubiese llegado a esto.

```
     setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
     set num=0
     for /f "tokens=*" %%h in (C:\$GET_POS\Bats_Aux\cajas.txt) do (
     set /a num=!num!+1
     set LIN_!num!=%%h
     echo %%h
     set ip=%%h
    set num1=!ip:~0,1!
    set num2=!ip:~1,1!
    set num3=!ip:~2,1!
    set num4=!ip:~3,1!
    set num5=!ip:~4,1!
    set num6=!ip:~5,1!
    set num7=!ip:~6,1!
    set num8=!ip:~7,1!
   set num9=!ip:~8,1!
   set num10=!ip:~9,1!
   set num11=!ip:~10,1!
   set num12=!ip:~11,1!
   set 
   final=!num1!!num2!!num3!.!num4!!num5!!num6!.!num7!!num8!!num9!.!num10!!num11!!num12!
   echo !final! >> getip.txt
   )
```

Saludos y gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 0):

Repitiendo cuatro veces la concatenación de subcadenas:

```
cat tmp.txt | while read linea; do
    set ip
    for i in {0..3}; do
        if (( $i>0 )); then
            ip+=".";
        fi
        ip+=${linea:i*3:3};
    done
    echo $ip;
    unset ip
done
```